# Its about the wheel size

Tags: tire

I have recently been scammed by a seller into giving me a 20inch wheel rather than a 26inch one. I didnt have time to check and have left that country where i bought it, forever. Now as i am 17 i cannot obviously fit into the 20inch wheels on my mtb bike. My question is can i replace its wheels with 26 inches one? Is it possible? I bought it for a hefty price and i cannot afford to discard it

Comment: What? Your bike was designed for a particular wheel size. You need to match the wheel size, hub size and type of brake needed.

Comment: Well thats a 200$ i wont ever get back

Comment: You make little sense.  The bike is designed for 26-inch wheels and you bought a 20.  Why did you need the wheel?  Can you just use your original wheel for awhile?  As to whether you can replace a wheel on a 26-bike with another 26-inch wheel, the answer is obviously "Yes", if you meet a few other criteria.

Comment: I didnt buy a wheel. I bought a bike with the 20inch wheels when i was thinking i bought the 26inch wheels one. Thats it.

Comment: The person selling it to me gave me the 20inch one instead of the 26inch one, for which i asked.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you bought a bike that comes with 20" or 26" wheels. You have 20's and want to know if you can mount 26's. This sounds unusual. Can you post a photo?

Comment: You are suffering from the logical fallacy of  "good money after bad"   If you've been scammed or conned, spending more money on the bike won't make it right.    Please post a clear and well lit photo of your bike from the right hand side into your question and we can help more.

Comment: Your other option is to take it up with the seller who has robbed you.  This would be a legal problem in your original country.  Can you contact someone locally to go and "visit" ?

Answer (score 6):

It is likely the bike frame will not allow you to put 26 inch wheels on a 20 inch bike frame.  They simply will no fit.  Sorry.  At this point, try to sell it as is and get a 26 inch bike.